# cmd prompt pass commands only if exe is already running

Tags: windows, command-line

i would like to know if it is possible to only pass the commands to a windows executable if it is already running...without starting a new instance of the exe.

basically in the string passed to cmd prompt:

directory_to_exe + command_to_send

if **directory_to_exe** is running, then only do the **command_to_send** part of the string to make current instance of exe accept the commands.

and not have two instances running.

hope this is clear.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `tasklist | findstr <command>` to see if it is already running.

Comment: Are you asking about some particular, existing program (if so, which one?) or are you asking what a program *could* do?

Comment: my question is from cmd prompt(dos) to an existing exe that accepts commands from cmd prompt.... so I can make the program do something but everytime I get a new instance of the program which I dont want.  I want to send the exe commands several times but not have a new exe each time...

Comment: i was pretty sure it couldnt be done in a simplistic fashion... but I took a chance anyways in case someone could provide some sort of idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but maybe not in the way you think.  The command line will start a second process, which can look for the first process (usually this is done with a named interprocess mutex), and can then send the command line over to the other process, which must be listening for such an interprocess message, using some kind of IPC such as mailslots, shared memory, named pipes, HTTP, etc.  The second process then exits after passing off the message to the first process.

Comment: thank you James. so it's not as straight forward as I'd hoped.